# getRemoseUser() returns null with a simple login html form

Tags: java, html, tomcat, netbeans

I'm a newbie with web technologies and I'm struggling with session tracking, in particular with user authentication.

I've this html page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Click
        <a href="login.jsp">here</a>
        to authenticate.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

which redirects to the following jsp:

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Login JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="LoginServlet" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="username">
            <input type="password" name="password">
            <input type="Submit" value="Conferma">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

where `LoginServlet` servlet has got the following method:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        String paramUser = request.getParameter("username");
        String paramPassword = request.getParameter("password");

        if(paramUser.equals("demo") && paramPassword.equals("demo")){
            // Success
            // Invalid session if existing
            HttpSession oldSession = request.getSession(false);
            if(oldSession != null)
                oldSession.invalidate();
            HttpSession currentSession = request.getSession(); // Creates new session
            currentSession.setAttribute(u, paramUser);
            currentSession.setAttribute(p, paramPassword);
            response.sendRedirect("success.jsp");
        }
        else{
            // Failed authentication
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        }
    }
}
```

Whose results are displayed by the following view:

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Success Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <p>Hello</p>
         <a href="LogoutServlet">logout</a>
         <%= request.getRemoteUser() %> <%--RETURN NULL--%>
    </body>
</html>
```

But unfortunately, in the jsp view `request.getRemoteUser()` returns `null` and I don't know why (and I want that it displays `"demo"` (the name of the logged user).

- Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0):

Just by setting arbitrary attributes on the session, the container (tomcat) won't arbitrarily and magically know the user.

You'll need to delegate authentication to tomcat so that the request can be properly initialized. The servlet specification names it "Container Managed Security", so it's standardized. The [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/realm-howto.html) has all the pointers you need - they involve configuration of a Realm, and changing your implementation to point to a different login URL - and not handling it. You won't see the user's password any more.

Comment: I was about to comment but you were faster. Right, he should have a look at j_security_check